# Android: Capture data sent from my Application?

Tags: android, networking

is there a way to Capture the data that sent from my Application over the internt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if there's any android specific ways, but you could run the application over WiFi and use Wireshark to view the raw packet data.

Comment: interesting! ill give it a try. i also wonder if there's an app for it on Android.

Comment: There is a wireshark app if you've rooted your phone. It'd be easier to use a desktop version, though. As for a dev tool to monitor network I/O either in the emulator or the device, if you find one, I want to know about it too.